# Connection fails to a PPTP server

Tags: pptp

I am having some problems connecting to my PPTP server. Sometimes I connect just fine but if I try in a few minutes, the connection may fail. I am connecting to Ubuntu 10.04 from Ubuntu 11.04 with no firewall from both sides. Here is my PPTP server config:

```
name PPTP
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
linkname PPTP
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
logfile /var/log/pptpd/pptp.log
lcp-echo-interval 5
lcp-echo-failure 5
```

I have enabled debug mode and here is what I get when the connection drops:

```
Connect: ppp2 <--> /dev/pts/3
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xc95722d2> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xe3d7a3fa> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xe3d7a3fa> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0xc95722d2> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xc95722d2]
sent [CHAP Challenge id=0x81 <103a6939c70d15a95e4d231af2a0ffce>, name = "PPTP"]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xe3d7a3fa]
rcvd [CHAP Response id=0x81 <fd82eda6eaced1d22e3dd26a9fb927cd44ffd7ff7e126e2fb00>, name = "user"]
sent [CHAP Success id=0x81 "S=AE573572293B3D5D62D1CA8A51A33E M=Access granted"]
Script /etc/ppp/auth-up started (pid 18107)
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
```

If I check the log for a successful connection, I get the follwoing line after the last line from the log above:

```
rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S +L -D -C>]
```

Please help me to elaborate this issue. Why don't I get the received answer from MPPE?
Thank you.